# Magento where to put js in this layout?

Tags: magento

I added the js using

addJs

in below code its my layout file so where I want to put my jquery.js file
please provide me path

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="addJs"><script>my_extension/jquery.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

I am referring this

http://www.activo.com/how-to-load-jquery-and-prototype-in-magento-admin-panel

but where to place my js file?

I am not geeting this

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the adminhtml as you wrote, then just put it in `js/my_extension/`

Answer (score 1):

Create local.xml file in your themes layout directory and place your code like this and place your js file here **"/skin/frontend/INTERFACE/THEME/js/"**. If you use addjs methods you have to place your js file under **"your magento root/js/"** folder. Here is an example.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <!-- Magento looks in /skin/frontend/<INTERFACE>/<THEME>/js/buyprinting.js
        for this file -->
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/buyprinting.js</name></action>
        <!-- This removes the item that was set in the page.xml file -->
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/iehover-fix.js</name></action>

        <!-- Magento looks in /js/prototype/element.storage.js for this file -->
        <action method="addJs"><name>prototype/element.storage.js</name></action>

    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Note:
If you still unsure where to place your js file go to your browser and click on view source. Here check your js file and place the js file accordingly.

Comment: he is talking about the adminhtml :)